# How do you transform a directional light to screen coordinates in modern GLSL?

Tags: opengl, glsl

I am switching my shaders away from relying on using the OpenGL fixed function pipeline. Previously, OpenGL automatically transformed the lights for me, but now I need to do it myself.

I have the following GLSL code in my vertex shader:

```
//compute all of the light vectors. we want normalized vectors 
//from the vertex towards the light
for(int i=0;i < NUM_LIGHTS; i++)
{
    //if w is 0, it's a directional light, it is a vector 
    //pointing from the world towards the light source
    if(u_lightPos[i].w == 0)
    {
        vec3 transformedLight = normalize(vec3(??? * u_lightPos[i]));
        v_lightDir[i] = transformedLight;
    }
    else
    {
        //this is a positional light, transform it by the view*projection matrix
        vec4 transformedLight = u_vp_matrix * u_lightPos[i];

        //subtract the vertex from the light to get a vector from the vertex to the light
        v_lightDir[i] = normalize(vec3(transformedLight - gl_Position));
    }
}
```

What do I replace the ??? with in the line `vec3 transformedLight = normalize(vec3(??? * u_lightPos[i]));`?

I already have the following matrices as inputs:

```
uniform mat4 u_mvp_matrix;//model matrix*view matrix*projection matrix
uniform mat4 u_vp_matrix;//view matrix*projection matrix
uniform mat3 u_normal_matrix;//normal matrix for this model
```

I don't think it's any of these. It's obviously not the mvp matrix or the normal matrix, because those are specific to the current model, and I'm trying to convert to view coordinates. I don't think it's the vp matrix either though, because that includes translations and I don't want to translate a vector.

Can I compute the matrix that I need from what is currently given to the shader, and if so, what do I need to compute? If not, what matrix do I need to add and how should it be computed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the same view_projection matrix. Yes, that matrix *does* include a translation, but because the light vector has w = 0 the matrix multiplication will not apply it.

Comment: This answer led me in the right... direction ;) However, I only had to multiply my light's position (which is passed to the vertex shader in local object-space) by the view matrix, not the view-projection matrix as suggested here. I was originally (and incorrectly) multiplying the light's position by the model-view matrix, b/c I thought I first had to move the light from local to world, and then to view, when only a direct-to-view transformation was needed. Glad I don't have to post a question now.

Answer (score 5):

You are supposed to transform the light position/direction into view space on the *CPU*, not in a shader. It's a uniform; it's done once per frame per light. It doesn't change, so there's no need to have *every* vertex compute it. It's a waste of time.